# BootStrap not getting applied to the Modal

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use Bootstrap Login modal in my react app but somehow Bootstrap CSS is not getting applied.

Code:

index.js

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Login.js
`

```
import React from 'react'
 const Login = (props) =>{
return(
<div>
<div id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">***Sign*** in</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

`

The expected output should be as per the reference for Bootstrap Modal:

https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/1891794?action=prism_export

The output I am having :

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code and your dependencies?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: That code snippet uses jQuery too, have you imported that?

Comment: This is not the React version, they got another version for [React](https://react.mdbootstrap.com/modals/modal-form)

Comment: From my understanding, the login form using modal is ready to use. I have placed the code in my login component and expecting  it to work. I have install bootstrap and also added bootstrap css file in the index.js. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong. Thanks.